# Replacing words with asterisks: parts of the pattern string are replaced as well

Tags: python

I'm trying a homework assignment wherein I should censor some words from a sentence. There is a list of words to be censored and the program should censor those words in the sentence it gets from user input.

I have already solved the problem, but along the way I tried something that I also expected to work, but it didn't. Below are the two different programs, one of which works and the other that doesn't. The only difference is in the line where the *word_list[i]* gets searched in *fin*.

```py
from cs50 import get_string
from sys import argv


def main():
if len(argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python bleep.py dictionary")
        exit(1)

    fin = open(argv[1])
    print("What message would you like to censor?")
    message = get_string()
    word_list = message.split()

    # This variant works.
    for i in range(len(word_list)):
        if (word_list[i].lower() + '\n') in fin:
            word_list[i] = '*' * len(word_list[i])
        fin.seek(0)

    # The following doesn't work.
    # for i in range(len(word_list)):
    #    if word_list[i].lower() in fin.read(): 
    #        word_list[i] = '*' * len(word_list[i])
    #    fin.seek(0)

    print(' '.join(word_list))

    fin.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Let's say I wanted to censor "heck" with ****, but the second program also censors a string like "he" which is only a part of "heck".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem ist that `"he" in "heck"` is True.

The first code gets around this by ensuring that the word ends with `\n`.

Another point: you are reading the file for each word in the user input. It is much more efficient and prob. much easier to write, read and debug to read the file once and store it in a string (or better a list of the splitter string)